# Get prevvious value of a column and create vector of cumsum

Tags: r, cumsum

I have following R code:

```
>a
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

I want to create b such that b[i] = a[i] + b[i-1].

Need help, how to do above action in R.

Comment: What is b[1] ? you haven't defined it

Answer (score 0):

```
b <- cumsum(b) + a
```

wil do the trick.

Comment: ??  you never even initialized `b`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Rgames> a <- 1:5
Rgames> b<-rep(7,5)
Rgames> b[-1]<-b[1:(length(b)-1)]+a[1:(length(a)-1)]
Rgames> b
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

You haven't stated whether you expect to add the updated value of `b[j-1]` to the new value of `b[j]` .